# How to link to custom "archive like" page with custom permalink rules "dynamically"

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am working on a plugin where I am trying to create a "archive like" page with permalinks.

Here is what I have so far:

1. I've created a query var "experience"
2. I've created custom SQL selects using - "post_join" and "post_where" hooks
3. I've created a custom template using the "template_redirect" hook
4. I've added custom permalink rules and flushed them

All good so far, the only thing I'm not getting is how I can link to my new archive like page "dynamically".

I can create a static link like mysite.com/experience/id - but this will not work when permalinks are off.

Also I tried to generate the URL like

```
<a href="' . add_query_arg( 'experience', $id, get_bloginfo('url') ) . '">url</a>
```

This works when permalinks ar off and also when on, but this not changes to mysite.com/experience/id when they are on. 
It always remain mysite.com/?experience=id

So what I would like to understand is how can I create those permalinks dynamically, so they will be recognized depending if permalinks are on/off.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a function that checks if permalinks are on by checking whether `get_option( 'permalink_structure' )` is empty or false and generates the appropriate link given the `$id`.

Something along the lines of the `get_permalink()` function which either looks at the `$post` global or looks at the `$id` passed into it.